# jQuery ui autocomplete usin JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am  having some trouble getting autocomplete to work specifically with a json file. It 
giving following error whenever something is entered in the text box

**url is undefined**

following is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    minChars: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {
            var url='dataa.json';

        $.getJSON(url,{term: request.term},function(data){

            response($.map(data.ledgers, function(item) {
            return item.value;
        }));
    })
    }
});
});
```

and the JSON

```
{
"ledgers": 
[
{
    "id":"2001",
    "name":"Bharat"
},
{
    "id":"2003",
    "name":"Gaurav"
},
{
    "id":"2002",
    "name":"Pankaj"
},
{
    "id":"2022",
    "name":"Purchase"
},
{
    "id":"2007",
    "name":"Ram"
},
{
    "id":"2008",
    "name":"Ramesh"
},
{
    "id":"2009",
    "name":"Suresh"
}
]}
```

Comment: I prepared page with the code you provided and it works. Tried in Chrome, not sure whether other browser will make any difference. Did you try use this script in isolation from your main app as I did?

Comment: your code doesn't throw any error

Answer (score 2):

Your [JSON file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194572/json-format-for-jquery-ui-autocomplete) needs to contain `value` or `label` (or both). Change `name` to `value` and it should work fine.

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    minChars: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {
            var url='dataa.json';

        $.getJSON(url,{term: request.term},function(data){
            response($.map(data.ledgers, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value,
                    value: key
                };
            }));
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`'use strict';`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it) at the top of your `$(document).ready()`. That may point out what the problem is...

```
return item.value;
```

`item` does not have a `value`, try returning `id` or `name`, which it does have.